# Derived template class with std::array size type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm using `C++17` and have a template class with restrictions on the template variable type. I want to add a derived class that additionally takes in a `std::array` parameter and templatize the size of the array.

```
template <typename T,
typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>>>
class Base {
public:
    Base(T param1) : value(param1) {}

    T value;
};


template <typename T,
typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>>,
typename N = unsigned int>
class Derived : public Base<T, U>
{
public:
    Derived(T param1, std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N>&& param2) :
        Base(param1),
        arr(std::move(param2)) {}

    std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N> arr;
};

// We can use Base as such
Base<int> b { 23 };
// I want to use Derived in such a way
Derived<int, 2> d {0, {{1, true}, {2, false}} };
```

However, I am having trouble getting this to build or creating instances of the derived class. Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
Added in the suggestions provided by switching variables and untemplatizing the N.
Here's a MRE https://godbolt.org/z/MGj5YdbxP
with new error with creating derived instance.

Edit2:
I know about the sfinae and will fix that. Is there a way to get it working for r-val reference so I can move the 2nd param? https://godbolt.org/z/YxYssKPn3
Suppose I also support large std::string types for T that will be destroyed.

Comment: please provide a [mre] including the full error messages

Comment: Perhaps exchange `U,N` positions and make `N` `std::size_t` instead of a type ? This way the two from `Derived<int,2>` is assigned to `U` instead of `N`

Comment: There is not much point in taking the second argument by && (the type will not gain much from moving). And if you do you have pass `std::move(a)`. More normally just take the second argument of Derived constructor by value or by `const &`. https://godbolt.org/z/h8YsE8xsG

Comment: @alfC what if I also support std::string types for T and want to move very long strings that will soon be destroyed. Is there a way to get it working for r-val ref?

Comment: Good question, I think the move is not automatically transitive through `std::array` (maybe it is through `std::pair`). I have to see it in actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC ,I made 2 changes to your code:

1.from  `Derived(T param1, std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N>&& param2) : Base(param1),`
to  `Derived(T param1, std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N>&& param2) : Base<T,U>(param1),`

2.from `template <typename T, typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>>, typename N = unsigned int>`

to `template <unsigned int N ,typename T, typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>> >`

here is the code:

```
#include<array>
#include<map>

template <typename T,
    typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>>>
    class Base {
    public:
        Base(T param1) : value(param1) {}

        T value;
};


template <unsigned int N
    ,typename T,
    typename U = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>>
    >
    class Derived : public Base<T, U>
{
public:
    Derived(T param1, std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N>&& param2) :
        Base<T,U>(param1),
        arr(std::move(param2)) {}

    std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N> arr;
};

// We can use Base as such
Base<int> b{ 23 };

int main() {
// I want to use Derived in such a way
    Derived<2, int> d{ 0, { std::make_pair(1, true), { 2, false } } };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like how you kept the r-val ref but is there a way to get it working by passing in the std::array instead of defining it inside `d`?

Comment: use `std::move`? 
 ```  
std::array<std::pair<int, bool>, 2> myarray;;
 myarray[0] = std::make_pair(1, true);
 myarray[1] = std::make_pair(2, false);
 // I want to use Derived in such a way
 Derived<2, int> d( 0, std::move(myarray) ); 
```

Comment: seems I may have to use std::move... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just reorder parameter, and use not-type template parameter:

```
template <typename T,
          std::size_t N,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int> || std::is_same_v<T, bool>, int> = 0>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
// ...
};
```

Note: `typename U = std::enable_if<condition>` doesn't enable SFINAE.
You need `typename U = std::enable_if_t<condition>` or `typename U = typename std::enable_if<condition>::type`.
That form might be hijacked (as you do with `Base<T, U>`); prefer `std::enable_if_t<condition, int> = 0`.

Comment: Yes I will use enable_if_t and know how it works thanks. That is not the part I'm having trouble with for this question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Derived(T param1, std::array<std::pair<T, bool>, N>&& param2)
> ```

The second template argument used for `std::array` in this constructor, `N`, is a *type* (template parameter) here, whereas `std::array` expects a valid argument for a non-type template parameter of type `std::size_t`.

It seems you want to parameterize your `Derived` type on a non-type template parameter of type `std::size_t`.